# Index RN used with incremental while joining

Tags: mysql

If the index on a table is `rn` and I am using `rn-1` or `rn+1` while joining, does it still work?

Comment: Please add your table definition and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does, incrementing on the index column keeps the index in place.